Getting boundaries for admin levels from O5m files using osmfilter while ignoring dependencies
Using osmfilter, I tried extracting all elements with tags admin_level=4 and boundary=administrative as follows:
osmfilter --keep="boundary=administrative and admin_level=4" -o="AdminLevel4.osm" ..\morocco-latest.o5m

It turns out I was getting a whole bunch of dependent information. For example, relation ID 2429544 has the following tags:
<tag k="admin_level" v="5"/>
<tag k="boundary" v="administrative"/>

The reason it is included is that, higher up, the relation with ID 1719443 - which does have tags matching with the object filter I have specified -  includes it as a member:
<member type="relation" ref="2429544" role="subarea"/>

I tried using the ignore-dependencies flag to remediate this but it turns out without the dependencies the relations and ways that depend on them which do have admin_level=4 cannot be geographically described (they cannot be plotted on QGIS). This makes sense because even a node whose tags don't match the object filter when using the ignore-dependencies flag will be thrown out. So the basic XY information isn't there.
However, the dependencies are cluttering the map and making it difficult to see what I need to see. How can I further tweak the object filter in osmfilter to get what I want?
